# No reducer provided for key "admin" error in react admin

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, react-admin

I am using redux in my react-admin panel. I am following the document [Including React-Admin In Another Redux Application](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CustomApp.html#using-an-existing-redux-provider)

But I get this error.

**No reducer provided for key "admin"**

[image]

I think **adminReducer** can not import from "react-admin".I faced this error after upgrading my react admin from 3.18 to 4.0.0. Is it related to version mismatch?

Here my **createAdminStore.js**

```js
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose, createStore } from "redux";
import { routerMiddleware, connectRouter } from "connected-react-router";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import { all, fork } from "redux-saga/effects";
import { adminSaga, adminReducer, USER_LOGOUT } from "react-admin";

export default ({ authProvider, dataProvider, history }) => {
  const reducer = combineReducers({
    admin: adminReducer,
    router: connectRouter(history),
    // add your own reducers here
  });
  const resettableAppReducer = (state, action) =>
    reducer(action.type !== USER_LOGOUT ? state : undefined, action);

  const saga = function* rootSaga() {
    yield all(
      [
        adminSaga(dataProvider, authProvider),
        // add your own sagas here
      ].map(fork)
    );
  };
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

  const composeEnhancers =
    (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" &&
      typeof window !== "undefined" &&
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ &&
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
        trace: true,
        traceLimit: 25,
      })) ||
    compose;

  const store = createStore(
    resettableAppReducer,
    {
      /* set your initial state here */
    },
    composeEnhancers(
      applyMiddleware(
        sagaMiddleware,
        routerMiddleware(history)
        // add your own middlewares here
      )
      // add your own enhancers here
    )
  );
  sagaMiddleware.run(saga);
  return store;
};
```

Comment: Can you share github link of your project?

Comment: @danimadmolil https://github.com/sayinmehmet47/electronic-products47